# PHP - Como percorrer um array de radios?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, array, sql-insert, radiobutton

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($alunosTurma)){ ?>
          <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['NM_NIS_ALU']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['ST_NOME_ALU']; ?>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['ID_ALUNO_ALU']; ?>" name="aluno[]">
                <!-- <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $idTurma; ?>" name="turma[]">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $dtChamada; ?>" name="data[]"> -->
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="options[]" value="0"><i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i>
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="options[]" value="1"><i class="fa fa-times text-danger"></i>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
```

Isso cria uma tabela listando todos os alunos e coloca à frente de cada um dois rádios (um de presença e um de falta).
No arquivo que faz o input no banco (ou deveria) tenho o seguinte:

```
$data = $_GET['dtChamada'];
$turma = $_GET['idTurma'];
$aluno = $_POST['aluno'];
$status = $_POST['options'];
$cont = 0;
foreach ($aluno as $idAluno) {
mysql_query(" INSERT INTO CHAMADA (DT_CHAMADA_CHMD, ID_TURMA_TUR, ID_ALUNO_ALU, FL_STATUS_CHMD) VALUES ('$data', '$turma', '$idAluno[$cont]', '$status[$cont]') "));
print_r("$data<br>");
print_r("$turma<br>");
print_r("$aluno[$cont]<br>");
print_r("$status[$cont]<br><br>");
$cont++;
}
?>
```

Para o primeiro aluno chegam os dados como preciso, mas do segundo em diante o status (presença ou falta) dá o seguinte erro:

> ```
> **Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\NISFRAM\processa\lancaChamada.php on line 26**
> ```

Como posso percorrer cada aluno gravando seu status no banco?

Comment: Como o foreach não precisa indexar o array, basta `$idAluno`

Answer (score 0):

A Tabela

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($alunosTurma)){ ?>
          <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['NM_NIS_ALU']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['ST_NOME_ALU']; ?>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['ID_ALUNO_ALU']; ?>" name="aluno[]">
                <!-- <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $idTurma; ?>" name="turma[<?php echo $row['ID_ALUNO_ALU']; ?>]">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $dtChamada; ?>" name="data[<?php echo $row['ID_ALUNO_ALU']; ?>]"> -->
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="options[<?php echo $row['ID_ALUNO_ALU']; ?>]" value="0"><i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i>
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="options[<?php echo $row['ID_ALUNO_ALU']; ?>]" value="1"><i class="fa fa-times text-danger"></i>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
```

O PHP

```
<?php
$data = $_GET['dtChamada'];
$turma = $_GET['idTurma'];
$aluno = $_POST['aluno'];
$status = $_POST['options'];

foreach ($aluno as $idAluno) {
mysql_query(" INSERT INTO CHAMADA (DT_CHAMADA_CHMD, ID_TURMA_TUR, ID_ALUNO_ALU, FL_STATUS_CHMD) VALUES ('$data', '$turma', '$idAluno', '$status[$idAluno]') "));
print_r("$data<br>");
print_r("$turma<br>");
print_r("$aluno[$idAluno]<br>");
print_r("$status[$idAluno]<br><br>");
}
?>
?>
```